# Symfony - API Platform , call api

Tags: php, symfony, orm, api-platform.com

hello I just created a project with symfony 3.3 and added it as an API Platform bundle, followed all the steps in the documentation and created an example entity called "Product".

The example is like this

```
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
public $id;

/**
 * @param string $name A name property - this description will be available in the API documentation too.
 *
```

If I access my project with the url http: // localhost / api / product I get the swagger screen where I see the actions

[image]

My question is how to make the call to these methods from the controller, this is my doubt.

Thank you

Comment: Why would you make such calls from inside your controller?

Comment: I have thought is to have in the same project that the API have the controllers that make use of that API.

The configuration of the project will be a Symfony project and using API platform as a bundle, in this way API Platform will put the models and I will have the API built and ready to use.

Now I need to do the "client" part that is in charge of making calls to the API and this is what I do not know how to do, this step.

Thank you

Comment: A client is nothing else than a controller making an HTTP request, use a library like [HTTPlug](http://httplug.io/) or any other to make such calls and that's it. api-platfform just provide you with an easy way to get your RESTful API ready to go in minutes.